# Want to use a variable in excel formula without vba

Tags: excel-formula

i have a formula like which is trying to sum a range ex: =Sum(C2:C25)

in this i want to change 25 to 26, 27, 28 etc. 
Can i declare it as a variable in a cell and how to use it in syntax?? 
I know how to do it in vba. 
Can it be done without VBA???

Answer (score 1):

The formula `=SUM(C2:OFFSET(C2;A1;0))`, where cell A1 would hold the number of elements to add minus 1, should give the desired result.

Comment: this worked. there is a minor correction in your formula though. comma to be used instead of semicolon

Comment: ; instead of , is a regional setting depending what part of the world your computer is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Non volatile formula option

### INDEX

Similar to what robert used but using a non volatile option.  Setup A1 to be the number of rows to sum over.

```
=SUM(C2:INDEX(C:C,A1+1))
```

The only caveat to the above, is A1 needs to be an integer greater than 0 I believe.

The difference between a volatile and nonvolatile formula is that a volatile formula will recalculate every time anything on the sheet changes.  A non volatile formula will only recalculate when some that affects the formula changes.  For a few cells containing volatile formulas, not a big deal.  However as the number of volatile formulas increase then moving around your spreadsheet will start to bog down.  one way around this is to set calculations to manual instead of automatic.